# Spring-Boot bean failed to create when using Google Cloud Pub/Sub message subscriber implementation

Tags: spring-boot, netty, grpc, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to run a project which has Spring-Boot, Google Cloud Pub/Sub with subscriber implementation, its giving following error

```java
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name \u0027pubsubProducer\u0027 defined in URL [jar:file:PubsubProducer.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find TLS ALPN provider; no working netty-tcnative, Conscrypt, or Jetty NPN/ALPN available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:584)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1244)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593)
    ... 27 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find TLS ALPN provider; no working netty-tcnative, Conscrypt, or Jetty NPN/ALPN available
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.defaultSslProvider(GrpcSslContexts.java:258)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.configure(GrpcSslContexts.java:171)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.forClient(GrpcSslContexts.java:120)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder.buildTransportFactory(NettyChannelBuilder.java:436)
    at io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.build(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:509)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:223)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:169)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.getTransportChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:156)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:157)
    at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.stub.GrpcPublisherStub.create(GrpcPublisherStub.java:164)
    at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Publisher.\u003cinit\u003e(Publisher.java:152)
    at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Publisher.\u003cinit\u003e(Publisher.java:82)
    at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Publisher$Builder.build(Publisher.java:597)
```

I was able to run this project but something has changed and now I can't run it on Linux Fedora 30 machine but on Windows its running fine, I have looked what might trigger this but they say I have different versions of `grpc-netty` and `grpc-netty-shaded`, but they are the same `1.21.0`.

Also, I'm only using the `google-cloud-pubsub-client` and have no control on its version. Do I need to install as package locally as well? I found some for grpc and netty in RPM.

Any help is appreciated, if you need anything else please comment.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody had answer my question, I will put it for future reference.

As I was on Fedora 30, it was missing a library `libxcrypt-compat`, after installing it, build ran successfully.

Comment: I had to switch to different base image `FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk8:alpine-slim` in my dockerfile instead of openjdk one and activate Pubsub permissions for my nodepool.

Comment: I didn't had access to Dockerfile